# Passing textbox as an instance in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var ctrl = $("<input />").decimalControl(AllowedDecimalValues).ControlContainer();
$.fn.decimalControl = function (Decimalvalues) {
    var settings = {
        'maxLength': '25',
        'defaultvalue': '00.00',
        'name': 'decimalcontrol',
        'type': 'number'
    };
    settings.MaxDecVal = Decimalvalues;
    return $(this).ControlBuilder(settings);
};
$.fn.ControlBuilder = function (settings) {
    return this.val(settings.defaultvalue)
        .attr('name', settings.name)
        .attr('value', settings.defaultvalue)
        .attr('type', settings.type)
        .attr('size', settings.maxLength);
};
```

The first line of the above code throws an error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'decimalControl'.
```

Please provide help or a alternate solution.

Comment: Not surprising since you have 3 functions, but only 2 implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `.decimalControl()` method BEFORE your code uses it.  Put the first line of code that uses the `.decimalControl()` method after the `$.fn.decimalControl = function(...) {...}` line that adds that method.

Comment: I tried that too... that doesn't either... any other suggestions ?

Comment: @ShishirKumarM - If jQuery is installed, then the first issue here is that the method `decimalControl()` is not installed yet when you are trying to use it.  You need to fix the order of your code to fix that.  I've advised how to fix that.  I can't help further unless you do that and post a link to web page where that isn't working properly so we can debug further or provide info on the new error.  Perhaps there is some additional error also that you haven't described.

Comment: @ShishirKumarM, usually you are encouraged to reply something more meaningful

Comment: @jfriend00 : Its working I tried pasting the first line at the end after all the functions are defined. Now the line executes properly. Thank you so much...